# Dirac's Theory of magnetic monopoles

Tags: education, magnetic-monopoles

Can someone give a breif summary of Dirac's theory of [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) a rather simple way?
Please also tell what methods he used and key ideas presented in his paper. I am asking this because it is a very long document for me and some part requires a higher level of mathematics beyond my level as I am 14 year old. And as PhysicsSE is for my help so if any physicist who has  read that paper can surely help me...

Comment: Why don't you read Dirac's paper by yourself?
The link is given in the Wikipedia page you mentioned: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#cite_note-10

Comment: I am in 10 class and 14 year old....I understand the theory of Quantum Mechanics well but the mathematics is not so understandable to me. And also it will take a very very long time to go through it. Otherwise I have the PDF but as i a told you i am not able to fully understand it as some ideas are trapped in mathematics.

Comment: Well, I must admit, Dirac's paper
["Quantised Singularities in the Electromagnetic Field"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#cite_note-10)
is hard to understand, not only for class-10 students.
The Wikipedia section
[Dirac's quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Dirac's_quantization) gives an easier understandable summary
of its key idea.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Okay thank you